Res.redirect isn't compatible with async routes inRestify?
My Restify routes are async:
 server.get("/verify", async (req, res) => { }
Within such routes I have to redirect user's click from an email to some confirmation success html, as well as complete the journey on this route and do res.send
 res.redirect(
    {
     hostname: process.env.HOST,
       pathname: process.env.REDIRECT_PATH_VERIFY_SUCCESS,
      port: 80,
      secure: process.env.REDIRECT_SECURE,
     permanent: true,
    },
    next
  );
  res.send(200);
 return

This is not working. Node.js is throwing "ReferenceError: next is not defined" and the browser is swearing "Can't complete the chain".
Have checked other solutions suggest (req, res, next) which is a no-go. Async is working like a breeze.
Went the sync way, stripped all the code just to test whether redirect would work at all and it did.
But it's a dead end, because Mongoose won't run with a callback anymore - for all the good reasons:
"Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback"
Did try, did make "Callback Hell" out of my code, though it was all correct and it would work.
Please let me know if you have any ideas how to solve it.
Kind regards,
Yuri

Since this route is for email confirmation to catch the click from email and to spit out some html in return, the workaround is not to use res.redirect at all.
Instead, we spit out html the following way:
const html = "<html> EMAIL CONFIRMATION SUCCESSFUL! </html>";

res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
res.write(html);
res.end();

